# Why does the results of my most informative feature for binary classification is always the same in python?

Tags: python, classification, naivebayes, python-3.7

This is my full codes for most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification and Naive Bayes  that I have tried.

```
def most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification(vectorizer, classifier, n=100):

        """
        Identify most important features if given a vectorizer and binary classifier. Set n to the number
        of weighted features you would like to show.
        """
        counter = 1

        def read_counter():
            return loads(open("counter.json", "r").read()) + 1 if path.exists("counter.json") else 0

        def write_counter():
            with open("counter.json", "w") as f:
                f.write(dumps(counter))

        counter = 1

        counter = read_counter()
        atexit.register(write_counter)
        if counter == 6:
            counter = 0

        # additional stopwords to be remove
        # Open a file and read it into memory
        file = open('..\stopwords.txt')
        additional_stopwords = file.read()
        additional_stopwords = additional_stopwords.split()

        class_labels = classifier.classes_
        feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
        feature_names = [word for word in feature_names if word not in additional_stopwords]

        topn_class1 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[:n]
        topn_class2 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[-n:]

        # class_labels = category
        # coef = co-effecient
        # feat = most informative feature
        if counter == 1:
            for coef, feat in topn_class1:
                print(class_labels[0], coef, feat)
                print(class_labels)

            print()

            for coef, feat in reversed(topn_class2):
                print(class_labels[1], coef, feat)

        elif counter == 2:
            for coef, feat in topn_class1:
                print(class_labels[1], coef, feat)

            print()

            for coef, feat in reversed(topn_class2):
                print(class_labels[2], coef, feat)

        elif counter == 3:
            for coef, feat in topn_class1:
                print(class_labels[2], coef, feat)

            print()

            for coef, feat in reversed(topn_class2):
                print(class_labels[3], coef, feat)

        elif counter == 4:
            for coef, feat in topn_class1:
                print(class_labels[3], coef, feat)

            print()

            for coef, feat in reversed(topn_class2):
                print(class_labels[4], coef, feat)

        elif counter == 5:
            for coef, feat in topn_class1:
                print(class_labels[4], coef, feat)

            print()

            for coef, feat in reversed(topn_class2):
                print(class_labels[5], coef, feat)

        else:
            print("=== PLEASE RUN PROGRAM AGAIN TO VIEW THE CO-EFFICIENT FOR THE CHOSEN MODEL ===")


    '''=========================================================================================='''
    '''MEAN ACCURACY FOR 4 MODELS(NAIVE BAYES / LOGISTICS REGRESSION / LINEAR SVC / RANDOM FOREST)'''
    '''=========================================================================================='''
    # n_estimators is the number of trees to be used in the fores
    def mean_acc():
        models = [
            RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, max_depth=3, random_state=0),
            LinearSVC(),
            MultinomialNB(),
            LogisticRegression(random_state=0)]
        CV = 6
        cv_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(CV * len(models)))
        entries = []
        for model in models:
            model_name = model.__class__.__name__
            accuracies = cross_val_score(model, features, labels, scoring='accuracy', cv=CV)
            for fold_idx, accuracy in enumerate(accuracies):
                entries.append((model_name, fold_idx, accuracy))
        cv_df = pd.DataFrame(entries, columns=['model_name', 'fold_idx', 'accuracy'])

        print(cv_df.groupby('model_name').accuracy.mean())


    '''=========================================================================================='''
    '''NAIVE BAYES CLASSIFIER'''
    '''=========================================================================================='''


    def NB_func():
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['content'], df['cat_id'], random_state=0)
        count_vect = CountVectorizer()
        X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
        tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
        X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
        clf_NB = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
        print(clf_NB)

        # save the model to disk
        filename = '../dataanalysis/models/Naive_Bayes.sav'
        pickle.dump(clf_NB, open(filename, 'wb'))

        print()
        '''Print the prediction of the category from the unknown document'''
        # For now its not accurate due to insufficient sample data
        # print("NAIVE BAYES CLASSIFIER: ", clf_NB.predict(count_vect.transform([""])))
        print()

        print("===============================================")
        print("================= NAIVE BAYES =================")
        print("===============================================")
        most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification(tfidf, clf_NB, n=10)
```

The output when I run the NB_func() is:

The first time the program run:

```
3 -7.730506816516725 abato
3 -7.730506816516725 abdome abdome
3 -7.730506816516725 abdome erythema
3 -7.730506816516725 abdome erythema redness
3 -7.730506816516725 abdomen distended complaint
3 -7.730506816516725 abdomen ex drain
3 -7.730506816516725 abdomen hbs
3 -7.730506816516725 abdomen hbs kidneys
3 -7.730506816516725 abdomen insitu
3 -7.730506816516725 abdomen insitu pinkish

4 -7.254153151633855 assist function toileting
4 -7.331276619904304 bnoxl
4 -7.343069108877106 assist incontinence
4 -7.384156232690568 breath utcome ineffective
4 -7.387014055512514 arora plansfollow
4 -7.4053139680029565 agitated change
4 -7.410079385200252 ambulate using aid
4 -7.443599738543319 accompanied bedside complain
4 -7.44802940166431 alert comfortable afebrile
4 -7.455925447446086 absence urinary symptoms
```

The second time the program run:

```
 4 -7.730945941543211 abato
 4 -7.730945941543211 abdome abdome
 4 -7.730945941543211 abdome erythema
 4 -7.730945941543211 abdome erythema redness
 4 -7.730945941543211 abdomen distended complaint
 4 -7.730945941543211 abdomen ex drain
 4 -7.730945941543211 abdomen hbs
 4 -7.730945941543211 abdomen hbs kidneys
 4 -7.730945941543211 abdomen insitu
 4 -7.730945941543211 abdomen insitu pinkish

5 -7.254592276660341 assist function toileting
5 -7.331715744930789 bnoxl discharge previously
5 -7.3435082339035915 assist incontinence
5 -7.384595357717053 breathing
5 -7.387453180539 arora
5 -7.405753093029442 agitated change
5 -7.410518510226737 ambulate using
5 -7.444038863569804 accompanied bedside complain
5 -7.448468526690795 alert comfortable
5 -7.456364572472571 absence urinary symptoms
```

The third time the program run:

```
5 -7.730506816516725 abato
5 -7.730506816516725 abdome abdome
5 -7.730506816516725 abdome erythema
5 -7.730506816516725 abdome erythema redness
5 -7.730506816516725 abdomen distended complaint
5 -7.730506816516725 abdomen ex drain
5 -7.730506816516725 abdomen hbs
5 -7.730506816516725 abdomen hbs kidneys
5 -7.730506816516725 abdomen insitu
5 -7.730506816516725 abdomen insitu pinkish

6 -7.254153151633855 assist incontinence urine
6 -7.331276619904304 board
6 -7.343069108877106 assist indwelling
6 -7.384156232690568 breathing
6 -7.387014055512514 arora plansfollow watch
6 -7.4053139680029565 agitated change
6 -7.410079385200252 ambulate using aid
6 -7.443599738543319 accompanied bedside complain
6 -7.44802940166431 alert comfortable afebrile
6 -7.455925447446086 absence urinary symptoms
```

The forth time the program run:

```
6 -7.730492001996121 abato
6 -7.730492001996121 abdome abdome
6 -7.730492001996121 abdome erythema
6 -7.730492001996121 abdome erythema redness
6 -7.730492001996121 abdomen distended complaint
6 -7.730492001996121 abdomen ex drain
6 -7.730492001996121 abdomen hbs
6 -7.730492001996121 abdomen hbs kidneys
6 -7.730492001996121 abdomen insitu
6 -7.730492001996121 abdomen insitu pinkish

7 -7.25347933696348 assist incontinence urine
7 -7.3312618053837 board
7 -7.342671383051713 assist indwelling
7 -7.383811392545885 breathing decreased shortness
7 -7.3865695243404845 arora plansfollow watch
7 -7.405088464279118 agitated behaviour aggression
7 -7.4098105414391995 ambulating
7 -7.443278461891396 accompanied bedside
7 -7.4477507335224775 alert conscious
7 -7.455910632925482 absence urinary
```

The fifth time the program run:

```
7 -7.730945941543211 abato
7 -7.730945941543211 abdome abdome
7 -7.730945941543211 abdome erythema
7 -7.730945941543211 abdome erythema redness
7 -7.730945941543211 abdomen distended complaint
7 -7.730945941543211 abdomen ex drain
7 -7.730945941543211 abdomen hbs
7 -7.730945941543211 abdomen hbs kidneys
7 -7.730945941543211 abdomen insitu
7 -7.730945941543211 abdomen insitu pinkish

8 -7.254592276660341 assist incontinence urine
8 -7.331715744930789 board reassessment indicated
8 -7.3435082339035915 assist indwelling
8 -7.384595357717053 breathing free respiratory
8 -7.387453180539 aroun
8 -7.405753093029442 agitated behaviour aggression
8 -7.410518510226737 ambulate prior admission
8 -7.444038863569804 accompanied bedside
8 -7.448468526690795 alert afebrile complains
8 -7.456364572472571 absence urinary
```

The problem encountered is that why do I always get the same results whenever I run my program each time. The classes has the same results instead of a different one.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your output, but if I read it correctly: Your first set of prints are the same with each run, which means your printing function is returning equal importances for each term and printing the first 10 in alphabetical order. In the second chunk of prints, the order and score for each is different, so that is being updated with each run. What is your first chunk of prints printing, vs what the second chunk is printing?

Comment: @G.Anderson im trying to get the most informative words in each classes (i got classses 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8) I am curious why they are printing the same thing, is there a way to do a for loop somewhere in my codes to get different results  :(

Comment: So for each of the result outputs you pasted in your question, the first run gives all the same weights for all features (but different for each class), and the second returns different weights. Without rewriting your program from scratch, the best thing I can tell you is to take the individual functions and run them independently, and see if you get the expected results, before rolling them up together. That way you can see if/where it is breaking.

Comment: Actually, I see one MAJOR concern, which is that you vectorize and TFIDF transform your training sets, but I don't see where you use the same vectorizer and transformer objects on your x_test and y_test. I honestly am surprised it's not throwing you an error, but that would explain strange results.

Comment: @G.Anderson so u think there are problems with the codes that causes the strange results? :O

Comment: Obviously there is something odd going on. Either there is a problem in the code, or the data. Unless your text corpus is  an exactly uniform distribution of the words in your input features, correlated 1:1 to your target, then it's EXTREMELY unlikely that all of your word importances are completely equal. Of course, it's possible that I am misunderstanding your task and/or code